# Vampires that suck your fat away as an energy source?

Tags: creature-design

I want a vampire that instead of sucking blood as a mechanism of quickly sucking fat off people.
It has to be quick potentially leave the victim with a reasonable chance to survive.

I understand that human fat is mostly liquid oil encapsulated in small cell mebranes.
I also know that human fat is used to preserve minerals and vitamins under the skin.
So for a vampire sucking off a fattie would be healtier than the best diet on any fitness magazine.

Also this mechanism has to not involve any chewing, because at this point one could just cook some bacon..

Comment: Can't it just be Liposuction?

Comment: Maybe the vampire was a fame virology researcher discovered how to apply mRNA to break apart fat cells easily, the virus do not kill like ebola nor does it throws our immune system into chaos like SARS it just break down fats ;D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Thin needle-like tongue will work just fine.**

Let's do some calculations. A gram of fat is 9 calories. (That's 'calories' in the nutritional sense which means technically we should be using the term 'kcal'.) Fat has a density of 0.9 g/ml (compare to water at 1 g/ml). Assume these vampires want a relatively human-like diet, which means they'll want 2,000 or so calories a day, which means they'll need 222 grams of fat, or about 200 ml of fat per day. That's *tiny*. For comparison sake, an 8oz glass of water is *236* ml, which means your vampires will need less than a cup of fat a day for energy.

That being the case, there's no need to use a mechanism that will gather a large amount of fat - in fact, that'd be unhealthy for the vampire. A needle jabbed into the right place will gather up all the necessary fat within a few minutes. Kind of like a blood draw. Except, you know, with fat instead of blood. True, fat is thick and can jam the needle, but there's a very easy way to prevent this - a potent emulsifier.

Here's how it would work. The vampire would approach the target (preferably an overweight human) and extend their needle-like tongue right into the target's fatty area, something which, with practice, is easy enough to do. Then the vampire inject an emulsifier which helps break down the fat into manageable droplets and slurps the fat right back into its mouth.

The human will likely attempt to resist this process, so precautions are advised. I'd suggest chloroform or possibly an explanatory pamphlet about the benefit of liposuction, it really comes down to personal taste.

Comment: I wonder if the human would survive that. Is that emulsifier the same kind used in cosmetic liposuction or would it need to be more potent (and harmful)?

Comment: @KeizerHarm I guess if it is not completely toxic it will be slowly absorbed by the body and either processed by the liver or excreted through the skin after some days... So depending on the toxicity it could cause death or a few bubbles of infections... Or maybe nothing at all.

Comment: If it is so energy dense, it might be a good idea to make vampiric calorie requirements higher - tying it to increased powers

Answer (score 8):

**Do what sea lampreys do**

Sea lampreys are parasites that evolved from filter feeders. They have no jaws and their bodies are technically still adapted for a filter-feeding lifestyle. So what do they do? They have a protrusible, piston-like tongue covered in keratinous teeth that they jam into the bodies of their victims. The tongue is then churned around, reducing organs and tissue around the site of attachment into an organic slurry of blood and macerated tissue. Then they slurp up the resulting milkshake of tissue and filter the nutrients out of it that way. Hey, it's technically filter-feeding.

[image]

Comment: Lampreys are real-world body horror.